# Step #2: node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.X' not found (required by node)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-app-engine

All the hints that stackoverflow has given me are related to `local` (or self-hosted) application deployment. I want to do a deploy on Google Cloud App Engine but I get

```
Step #2: node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by node)
Step #2: node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.25' not found (required by node)
Step #2: node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by node)
```

I have a static app, written in ReactJS, with the help of boilerplate create-react-app.

This is my app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

runtime_config:
  runtime_version: "18"
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"

automatic_scaling:
  min_num_instances: 1
  max_num_instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: build/static

- url: /.*
  static_files: build/index.html
  upload: build/index.html
```

and this is the package.json part

```
{
  // rest
  "scripts": {
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "deploy": "yarn build && gcloud app deploy"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0"
  },
}
```

What I've done so far:

- logged in with SDK,
- checked billings; I have card added (one of answers on stack),
- adding `operating_system: "ubuntu22"` to `runtime_config` (Google docs about app.yaml and Node18)
- changed runtime version for 16

Still it crashes on 2nd step, with this library error. I can't install library... can I? Is there a special system image that I can put in `runtime_config`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't think it'll be such trivial thing. In [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime) there's point

> New runtime versions (Preview)
> For Node.js runtime version 18 and later you must include the runtime_config and operating_system settings in your app.yaml to specify an operating system. Node.js version 18 (preview) runs on Ubuntu 22.
> Your application must use a gcloud CLI version 420.0.0 or later. To view the current gcloud version, run the gcloud version command.

I assumed I had the most latest version because I had been using 'gcloud' at work. However, I discovered that I was using version '416,' and after updating it, the problem was resolved.